# Using jquery to determine selected option causes "specified attribute is deprecated" warning

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

Probably missing something pretty obvious but I can't figure out what is going on.  I am trying to use jquery to determine the currently selected option in a dropdown ([See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malonso/Ndzvm/)) but when I do something like the following I get a Warning in the (FF9) console.

```
var selectedValue=$('#testSelect option:selected').val();
```

Warning Message:

> Warning: Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this something I should be concerned with?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is driving me crazy too... did you find any solution or did you just forget about it?

Comment: @Mischa - I just let it go for the time being :(

Comment: I guess it's a bug in Firefox. It seems to be happening only with selects. What a waste of time...

Comment: Right now I only see this in Google Chrome's latest version, not Firefox's. Wonder why?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

jquery is referencing the "specified" property on an Attr object, this is depreciated with Firefox 7, and always returns true.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Attr

i've raised a jquery ticket for this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11397

Comment: The [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12072) is shown as "closed bug: fixed". Do I have to change anything in my code or will the next jQuery version just "fix" this? Perhaps I have to update my jQuery version used?

Comment: I am using $(this).get(0).value for now till they sort this out

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('change','select#FIELD_NAME', function() {
    alert('your selection was: '+$('select#FIELD_NAME').attr('value'));
    return false;
});
```

K.I.S.S. ...whenever it's possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ask the `select` tag for it's value, it knows which one is selected and will use that tag for it's current value.

```
$('#testSelect').val()
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ndzvm/1/

Sometimes it's simpler than you think it is :)

Comment: That's how it should be done, but doesn't really answer the question regarding the warning message. This also produces the same warning msg in the console.

Comment: Chrome actually seems to issue no warning in either version for me. I dont think that message is coming form jQuery.  But perhaps jQuery is just doing something that Firefox doesn't like.  At the end of that day warnings are just warnings, and if it works in all target environments then I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: @Alex - Sorry for my delay in responding to this.  As Shawn mentions, the method you described is valid but my question/concern was about the warning FF is throwing.  My apologies, the reason I used "#testSelect option:selected" instead of simply "#testSelect" was b/c I was ripping my hair out trying to figure out if any derivation of the selector would get rid of the warning message; it did not :(

Comment: Simpler code, but still produces the same warning (FF10 error console).

Comment: what if i want .text() of the selected option

Answer (score 0):

can you use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select[id$=<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>]').bind("keyup
change", function() {
if ($(this).val() != "")
$('#message').text("Text: " + $(this).
find(":selected").text()
+ ' Value: ' + $(this).val());
else
$('#message').text("");
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id #testSelect is your select name.

Get the value:

```
var selectedValue=$('#testSelect').attr('value');
```

Set the select value:

```
$('#testSelect').attr('value',your value);
```