# Jquery: Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have collection of select elements, when I change value of one select elements for first time this function dont work it works the second time I change value and in console I have [image: this]

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var collection = $('select.ddlJ');
    console.log(collection);
    for (var element in collection) {
        $(element).change(function () {

            $('select.ddlJ').change(function (e) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last').prev().find('span').html(
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('select.ddlJ').filter(function () {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'm';
                    }).length);

                $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last span').html(
                $(this).parent().parent().find('select.ddlJ').filter(function () {
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'n'; }).length);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" id="grid1"
   rules="all">
        <tbody><tr>
 <th scope="col">Nr de ord</th>
 <th scope="col">StudentId</th>
 <th scope="col">Name LName</th>

 <th scope="col">
      <span id="mondayText">monday<br></span>
      <span id="monday">14.05.2012</span>
  </th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="thuesdayText">thuesday<br></span>
     <span id="thuesday">15.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="wednesdayText">wednesday<br></span>
     <span id="wednesday">16.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="thursdayText">thursday<br></span>
     <span id="thursday">17.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="fridayText">friday<br></span>
     <span id="friday">18.05.2012</span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
     <span id="saturdayText">saturday<br></span>
     <span id="saturday">19.05.2012</span>
  </th>
   <th scope="col">
   <span id="M">Total1</span>
   </th>
  <th scope="col">
   <span id="N">Total2</span>
   </th>
               </tr><tr>
                <td>  1  </td>
                <td>110001</td>
                <td>Test1 Test1</td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_0" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl02$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a2222_0" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl02$a2222">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>

                          </td><td>
                          </td><td>
                          </td><td>
                          <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                          </td><td>
                           <span id="totalN"></span>
                          </td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td> 2   </td>
                <td>110002</td>
                <td>Test2 Test2</td>
                <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td><td>
 <select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_1" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl03$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>

                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                 </td><td>
                 <span id="totalN"></span>
                  </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                         3                  
                </td><td>110008</td><td>Test3 Test3</td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
<select class="ddlJ" id="a1111_2" name="ctl00$contentbody$grid1$ctl04$a1111">
                <option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
                <option value="m">m</option>
                <option value="n">n</option>
            </select>
                         </td><td>
                </td><td>
                </td><td>
                 <span class="label" id="totalM"></span>
                </td><td>
                  <span id="totalN"></span>
                          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code. And are you sure this notice is caused by changing the value of these elements (or could it be something else)?

Comment: BTW, rather than using .parent().parent(), you might want to use .end() instead to "undo" previous "destructive" chain operations.  I believe you will get better performance that way, though I did not actually measure this. http://api.jquery.com/end/

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML as well as JavaScript/jQuery.  To get a better answer more quickly, I highly recommend posting an example demonstrating the problem to an online tool like JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a bug in jQuery:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11397

(see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460682/1178235)

Comment: Please mark questions as duplicates instead of answering with a link to another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```js
var collection = $('select.ddlJ')
```

to use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
var collection = $('select.ddlJ').get();    
// BTW, this is similar to $('select.ddlJ')[0]
```

That gives you the actual DOM elements rather than a jQuery object matching them.  Alternatively (and the way I would probably do it), would be to instead change

```
for (var element in collection)
```

to use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('select.ddlJ').each(function(i, element) { ... });
```

Comment: I changed as you said and it's still the same                                  Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
[Break On This Error]  
...],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](...  jquery....min.js (line 2)

Comment: OK, then there is probably something else too, but that part jumped out to me as being a mistake.  I don't see anything immediately obvious in your code where you are accessing any attributes.  Do you encounter this error in all browsers?  Which one/version are you using?  I will look further if you can provide a live example (e.g. jsFiddle -- I'm happy to help solve the problem, but it doesn't make sense for me to try to reproduce your problem -- I just want to do the fun part :D)

Comment: Did this solve your problem?  I never saw the actual problem.  I'm assuming you got it working, but perhaps you might want to post some more information for other users who may have a similar problem.

Comment: I have the same warning in Firefox with Firebug and FireQuery installed. Using $("selector for select").val() gives me this warning. I am ignoring this warning as it doesn't seem to matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the .val() to .attr('value')

Comment: This stopped the error for me. But I read that .val() is preferred to .attr('value'), partiucularly for select boxes which is my situation...