# set select element value resulting error

Tags: jquery

I got this error after 2 lines of simple codes to set a SELECT value to a variable:

> Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true

Code:

```
var strMe = $("#o_productCategory").val();
alert(strMe);
```

No error message occurs when I use `o_productCategory.value;` but somehow it doesn't works in different browsers.

Comment: is that second line ? var strMe .....

Comment: `o_productCategory.value;` can only work in IE. But are you sure your error is here ?

Comment: See similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389841/using-jquery-to-determine-selected-option-causes-specified-attribute-is-depreca)

Comment: @Syon yes its works, but the warning on the debug screen is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$('#o_productCategory :selected').text();
```

Note : Only works if value and text are same...

Comment: hmm. need to tricks the value and label are same,.. btw, thanks