# $('select option:selected').text() and Attr.specified is deprecated warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my project I need to update a backbone model with both the selected value and text from a `<select>`.

For this purpose I am calling

```js
model.set 'value', $('select').val()
model.set 'value_text', $('select option:selected').text()
```

(I am using coffee script as well). Because of some problem in jQuery v2.0.3 which I am currently using I am receiving this warning:

> Attr.specified is deprecated. Its value is always true.

I know there were questions on SO about this warning, but I want to ask something completely different:

Since updating to a newer version of jQuery (where the problem might be fixed) is not possible in next few months I would like to ask whether there is other way round to receive the selected option's text instead of that used above. I am not against pure JS solution if there is no other using jQuery.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT** for @KevinB: The warning is caused by asking whether there is `selected` attribute on that option.

Comment: Did you try option:active? What pseudo selectors have you tried?

Comment: What exactly causes the warning? the use of :selected? or the use of .text on an option? .val() on a select?. Cutting out the part that causes it would obviously be the solution. That, or simply ignore the warning because coding around it is going to make the code less readable.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Also, apparently this doesn't affect jquery 1.10.1. (haven't tested this myself)

Comment: @KevinB Updated question... Simple googling for that warning could give you better results (what is causing it), but I understand that clicking on *Close > Unclear what are you asking* is so damn simple. Anyway, the question is clear enough - but instead of answering the question you just have to stir the mud around the warning... I have also mentioned that upgrading the jQuery is not possible now... And going from 2.0.3 to 1.10.1 does not look like upgrade at all...

Comment: because the warning is very important to the answer. You want to remove the warning right? also, i am not the close vote, this is a perfectly valid question (if it isn't a duplicate of something)

Comment: My suggestion is to first comment out the .val() usage to ensure that it is caused by the :selected psudo selector. If the warning still happens, replace :selected with a .filter.

Comment: Then I do not know who was voting for closing for that dumb reason as I do not find anything unclear on my question. Is there anything, be so kind and point that out.

Comment: @KevinB it is the `:selected` pseudo selector, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389841/using-jquery-to-determine-selected-option-causes-specified-attribute-is-depreca

Comment: then simply replace it with `.filter`. `$('select option').filter(function (i) { return this.selected; })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *fix* it without changing anything else, you can just use .filter.

```
$('select option').filter(function (i) { return this.selected; }).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer do that in a different approach. See the code.

Inside view.

```
events:
    "change input":"updateModel"
    "change select" : "SelectedItem" //Just for example.

selectedItem:(element)->
    selectedOption = element.target.selectedOptions
    alert **selectedOption.item().value** // the value of the selected item. now you can set it on model.

updateModel:(element)->
    @model.setNew(element.target.name, element.target.value)
```

Inside model.

```
setNew:(newName, newValue)->
    @set newName, newValue
```

Html file.

```
<select>
<option value="renan">Renan</option>
<option value="carvalho">Carvalho</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="customer" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works with `<input>` but not at all with `<select>` and it's options since the target is the `<select>` itself and since instead of element's `name` I need it's text...